# How to read all the content which is stored into a txt file?

Tags: c, file

How to read all the content which is stored into a txt file?

If I have a txt file with words in it and I want to read all of them and store them into a string how can I do it?

If I use `fscanf(in, "%s", string)` I only read the first word and when there is the first white space the `fscanf` stops its job. How can I read all of the words and store them in a string?

Comment: Use `fread`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how to slurp the entire contents of a file into a single buffer in memory, here's one way (assuming sufficient space in memory):

```
FILE *fp;
char *buffer = NULL;
size_t len, num_read;

fp = fopen("myfile", "r");
if(fp == NULL) // handle error...
{}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
len = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

buffer = malloc(len + 1);
if(buffer == NULL) // handle error...
{}

num_read = fread(buffer, 1, len, fp);
fclose(fp);

buffer[num_read] = '\0';

// buffer now contains the entire content of your file
use(buffer);

free(buffer);
buffer = NULL;
```

Comment: I think undefined behaviour applies to text mode, not binary mode; and `fseek(0,SEEK_END)` is valid also for text mode...

Comment: @StephanLechner See [footnote 268](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268) of the C standard

Comment: Hm - it seems that `fseek(0,SEEK_END)` is valid *only* for text mode. BTW: why are you using binary if OP wants to read a text file?

Comment: @StephanLechner Good point - it's just a habit when using `fread`. Updated my post to open in `"r"` mode & use the return value of `fread` to null-terminate `buffer`